# Is chaining CSS classes in such a way valid?

Tags: css

I've been relying on the following technique for a while. But I've not come across it often, and I wasn't able to find information on it. Perhaps it has a proper name that I am not aware of? I call it chaining because it seems to be exactly that: chaining CSS class names together. But doing a search on chaining yields info on jQuery for the most part.

```
.button {
   background-color:#ccc;
}
/* This is what I'm unsure of, notice there is no space between .button and .on */
/* If there were, .on apply to the child of .button, but that's not my intention */
.button.on { 
   background-color:#fff;
}
```

It allows me to use a single class name (on) to differentiate between the states of multiple elements.

```
<a class="button"></a>
<a class="button on"></a>
<a class="button-two"></a>
<a class="button-two on"></a>
<!-- etc... -->
```

It's very handy with dynamic pages when you need to toggle an `on` class on several elements using a single class name.

But is it valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is perfectly valid CSS....
Although IE6/and IE7 do have some issues with class-chaining.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is valid CSS, although it doesn't work quite right in IE6 - it will only apply the last class, rather than all of them. You can [read more over at CSS-Tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/5690-multiple-class-id-selectors/) on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly valid and very common.

You can see it in this very page:

```
a.comment-user.owner {
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

However, IE6 will ignore all but the last class.
In IE6, `.a.b` is equivalent to `.b`.